# Deletion of files inside vendor/composer/ - PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am working in a laravel project. Suddenly I am facing this error:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(/home/shafi/Projects/Lib/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/shafi/Projects/Lib/vendor/autoload.php on line 5 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/shafi/Projects/Lib/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/shafi/Projects/Lib/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

As the error message says I looked at the `vendor/composer/` folder which contains only

- autoload_classmap.php
- installed.json

But in another laravel project I found the following files in `vendor/composer/`:

- autoload_classmap.php
- autoload_psr4.php
- installed.json
- autoload_files.php
- autoload_real.php
- LICENSE
- autoload_namespaces.php
- ClassLoader.php

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Delete your vendor folder competely
2. Run `composer install`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just run `PHP` composer update:

```
composer update
```